# The Absolute Value of a Complex Number with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, absolute-value

I have the following script in Python. I am calculating the Fourier Transform of an array. When I want to plot the results (Fourier transform) I am using the absolute value of that calculation.
However, I do not know how the absolute value of complex numbers is being produced.
Does anyone know how it calculates? I need this to reproduce in Java.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import fft

inp = [1,2,3,4]

res = fft.fft(inp)

print(res[1]) # returns (-2+2j) complex number

print(np.abs(res[1])) # returns 2.8284271247461903
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sqrt(Re(z)**2 + Im(z)**2)
```

for `z = a + ib` this becomes:

```
sqrt(a*a + b*b)
```

It's just the euclidean norm. You have to sum the square of real part and imaginary part (without the i) and do the sqrt of it.

[image: absolute of complex number]

https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/absolute-value-complex-number

Comment: Thank you. Yes this returns the exact result.

Answer (score 10):

np.abs gives magnitude of complex number i.e. sqrt(a^2 + b^2) in your case it's sqrt(8).

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html

Answer (score 4):

From `numpy.absolute(arr, out = None, ufunc ‘absolute’)` [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html):

```
This mathematical function helps user to calculate absolute value of each element.
```

For a complex number a+ib, the absolute value is sqrt(a^2 + b^2).

Comment: Useful answer as well, resolved. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For complex valued pairs, `a+ib`, you can consider using the java Math static method *hypot*:

```java
Math.hypot(a, b)
```

The method is an implementation of the Pythagorean theorem, `sqrt(a*a + b*b)` but additionally provides underflow and overflow protection.